# Point Cloud Stanford Issue

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using blender 3.1 and have some issue with geometry nodes, I have a point cloud mesh in PLY and would like to know if there is anyway to apply noise to the vertices location to make it move or to turbulence it

Comment: Please [add some images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/260992/edit) of what you have now (including your node tree) and if possible an example of what you wish to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's coming from ply or any other format, it should be converted on import to either regular blender mesh object with vertices, or native blender point cloud objects, both of which you can tweak the positions using the same methods as with any other meshes

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this node group is one useful way of applying noise to position vectors:

[image: adding noise to position vectors]

I don't have a PLY file handy, but here's the result of using it on the Z coordinate of a grid:

[image: noise applied to a grid]

You can, of course, apply different noise to the X and Y coordinates.

You can animate the group by setting keyframes on the parameters of the noise texture, or even by making the group more complex and animating the additional nodes.